# How do you make changes from a new windowManager window?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, so I'm learning as I'm doing things. On my internship I was asked to adjust a WYSIWYG html editor so it can be used with e-mails. I'm using placeholders to later be replaced by the user.

My question: How do I detect the input in the textbox and replace it in the editor?

I had a look at other posts, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156221/get-input-field-value-from-dialog-box-in-tinymce) one, but I still can't get it to work.

My code so far:

```
setup: function(ed) {
    // on mouse up gets selected text
        ed.on('mouseup', function(ed, e) {
            var highlighted = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
            // Checks if highlighted texts contains a placeholder
            if (highlighted.indexOf("[!") > -1) {
                //alert(highlighted);
                tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'replace',
                    width: 320,
                    height: 240,
                    body: [
                        {type: 'textbox'}
                    ]
                })
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out already! Here is my code if people want to know how I did it:

```
setup: function(ed) {
    // on mouse up gets selected text
        ed.on('mouseup', function(ed) {
            var highlighted = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
            // Checks if highlighted texts contains a placeholder
            if (highlighted.indexOf("[!") > -1) {
                //alert(highlighted);
                tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'Replace placeholder',
                    file: 'namechange.html',
                    width: 320,
                    height: 80,
                })
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is how the 'namechange.html' file looks like:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="namechange"/>
    <input type="button" id="submit-namechange" value="Oké"/>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('submit-namechange').onclick = function(){
            var namechange = document.getElementById('namechange').value;

            window.parent.tinyMCE.get('editor1').selection.setContent(namechange);
            window.parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
        };
    </script>
    <script src="scripts/settings.js"></script>
</body>
```